# unexpected T_LNUMBER in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: php, curl, syntax

Hullo,
I am getting error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ')' in ... (line '__LASTFOCUS'=>'').

What is strange is that the error sticks in the same place even if I remove the reported line or even a bunch of lines around the error: what could it be? Are there limits on the number or size of curl postfields?

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        '__SPSCEditMenu'=>'true',
        'MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource'=>'',
        'MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId'=>'',
        'MSOTlPn_View'=>'0',
        'MSOTlPn_ShowSettings'=>'False',
        'MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary'=>'',
        'MSOGallery_FilterString'=>'',
        'MSOTlPn_Button'=>'none',
        '__EVENTTARGET'=>'',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT'=>'',
        '__REQUESTDIGEST'=>'0x2A02AA889D8390AB95007187B517EA1C6B4766D3B39A761AD5C5211782F7F2D1D35040A5592889C1171961C6C3679849C66993F246AE5292DF1BC3A19B405F9E,20 Dec 2012 11:25:09 -0000',
        'MSOAuthoringConsole_FormContext'=>'',
        'MSOAC_EditDuringWorkflow'=>'',
        'MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName'=>'Browse',
        'MSOWebPartPage_Shared'=>'',
        'MSOLayout_LayoutChanges'=>'',
        'MSOLayout_InDesignMode'=>'',
        'MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName'=>'Browse',
        'MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName'=>'false',
        '__LASTFOCUS'=>'',
        '__VIEWSTATE'=>$viewState,
        'ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_d50ea2f4_9347_49e0_9f8c_83b4ba8f7466_lines_type_rbl_2'=>'1',           
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d50ea2f4_9347_49e0_9f8c_83b4ba8f7466$lvsbm'=>'',         
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d50ea2f4_9347_49e0_9f8c_83b4ba8f7466$rd_ltype_ch'=>'0',  
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d50ea2f4_9347_49e0_9f8c_83b4ba8f7466$pg_v_pos'=>'0', 
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_6a113a00_1817_4823_834b_666b7bf38e10$nldpmt'=> '500',
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d50ea2f4_9347_49e0_9f8c_83b4ba8f7466$pg_v_pos=>'0',
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_6a113a00_1817_4823_834b_666b7bf38e10$txt_town'=>'milano',
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_6a113a00_1817_4823_834b_666b7bf38e10$hh_hn'=>'';
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_6a113a00_1817_4823_834b_666b7bf38e10$canshowroute'=>'1',
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_6a113a00_1817_4823_834b_666b7bf38e10$pg_v_pos'=>'0',          
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d50ea2f4_9347_49e0_9f8c_83b4ba8f7466$txt_dp_lines_9347_49e0_9f8c_83b4ba8f7466$txt_dp_lines'=>$line,       
        'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_bd2153c6_2f32_4bfa_8abb_504f3e53a69b$contextname'=>'5a4665da-c66a-4f84-87d27009ff396423-50d2f595'     
));
```

Comment: you missed `'` here: `'....pg_v_pos=>'0',`

Answer (score 1):

See this lines:

```
 'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d50ea2f4_9347_49e0_9f8c_83b4ba8f7466$pg_v_pos=>'0',
 'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_6a113a00_1817_4823_834b_666b7bf38e10$hh_hn'=>'';
```

Need to be:

```
 'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_d50ea2f4_9347_49e0_9f8c_83b4ba8f7466$pg_v_pos'=>'0',
 'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_6a113a00_1817_4823_834b_666b7bf38e10$hh_hn'=>'',
```

Don't you use syntax highlight in your IDE?
What IDE do you use?)

Comment: No one, actually, here at business I just use WinSCP. For that matter, any suggestion on a good editor on this platform, I use Textwrangler at home on the mac.

Answer (score 1):

Same as above, but there might be another problem:
`'ctl00$SPWebPartManager1$g_6a113a00_1817_4823_834b_666b7bf38e10$hh_hn'=>'';`
Remove the semicolon.

Comment: Right, I located that too: surely I miss the syntax checking of Xcode... thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You see it in the markdown editor.

You missed a `'`